# How to test and deploy after edit/commit in Google Cloud Source Repositories (CSR)?

Tags: git, google-app-engine

Managed to edit code and commit in CSR repo directly but don't understand correct workflow after that.

Specifically:

- How to pull committed code from CSR repo to project folder (ie. ~/src/project_folder), so that I can run dev_appserver.py to test?
- Is that done from inside CSR or do I use git to copy from repo to project_folder?

New to Google App Engine and Git. Any clues will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your CSR as a remote to your local repository and then do a git pull to get the changes. Follow instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/adding-repositories-as-remotes#use_the_cloud_source_repository_as_a_remote).